# How to split a total contract value into equal monthly values, starting from the contract start date, in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to create a formula to populate monthly columns with monthly revenue based on the total contract value being split evenly between the duration of the contract, starting from the date that the contract will be signed. The information I currently have in my report is the start date, the total contract value and the duration (in months). I know I could easily calculate the monthly value and then manually enter that amount into every month but I have a report with hundreds of entries so need a formula I can apply to each entry.

The format I am thinking of (but I am open to other suggestions!) is as below...

[image]

What I am hoping it will look like with the magic formula would be this (I have typed this one manually)...

[image]

I should then be able to create a pivot table to summarise the monthly revenue forecast.

I do not need the formula to calculate partial months, e.g. if the contract starts mid-month it is fine for that to count as a full month of revenue. If there is an easier way that splitting this into monthly columns that's not a problem - it is only the summary information that will be presented on my report.

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how I can do this and let me know if you need any clarification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell `D2`, copy / paste this formula: <sub><sup>(You may have to change commas to semicolons depending on your regional settings.)</sup></sub>

```
=IF(AND(D$1>=DATE(YEAR($A2),MONTH($A2),1),D$1<=DATE(YEAR($A2),MONTH($A2)+$B2,1)),$C2/$B2,"")
```

Breaking it down, the logic is this:

```
IF
   (the date in row 1 is >= the first day of the contract start date month)
   AND
   (the date in row 1 is <= the first day of the month of the contract start date plus the duration in months)
THEN
   calculate the total value divided by the number of months
ELSE
   return blank (change "" to 0 or "-" or whatever fits your need)
```

The key point in this is that the values in the first row - the column headings - are actual dates and not text. The way the formula is written, those dates needs to be the first of every month. That's not difficult if you type the first two or three and then drag the rest across; Excel will increment automatically. If this is a problem, let me know and we can find another means.

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much! Exactly what I needed :)